# Anomaly I and II appear(s) to have ...[or appear?]

Tags: grammatical-number

This sentence is to say anomaly number 1 and number 2 have higher soil iodine concentration than other anomalous areas.

Should it be plural or singular? i.e. 'appear' or 'appears'?

Thanks!

Comment: *A and B* is plural. *A and B appear to have...*

Comment: *anomalies* number 1 and number 2 *have* or *anomaly* number 1 and *anomaly* number 2 *have*. E.g. *Samples 1 and 2 are* but not *Sample 1 and 2 are*.

Comment: This may interest you: [ell.se]

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of a compound subject. There are two subjects, and therefore it is plural. Use "appear." This is like John and Mary have a house. There are two of them.

Answer (score 0):

First off, we need to correct "anomaly number 1 and number 2:" it's either

> **anomalies** number 1 and number 2,

or

> anomaly number 1 and anomaly number 2

That resolves the issue with the verb's number: in either case, we need to use *appear* without the *s* to agree with *(both the) anomalies* and with *have.* (Well the word *have* should have straightaway hinted you that *appear* would be right.)